# Handlebars method call doesn't return a value

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I use handlebars. I registered a helper who call a function.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("getContactCategoryById", getContactCategoryById);
```

Function

```
function getContactCategoryById(categoryId) {
    var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");

    $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(category), function () {
        if (this.contactCategoryId == categoryId) {
            return this.name;
        }
    });
}
```

In my template, my function is called and when i debug, getContactCategoryById return a value, but it never displayed in the table.
I can see when i see html code then contact-category-id have a value for data-contact-category-id tag.

```
<script id="lodger-contact-available-result-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table id="lodgerContactAvailableTableResult" style="min-height:200" data-show-header="true" class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-height="330">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each this}}
    <tr>
    <td data-contact-category-id={{contactCategoryId}}>{{getContactCategoryById contactCategoryId}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
    </table

</script>
```

Edit: solution, need to do a return to exist the each and get the value

```
function getContactCategoryById(categoryId) {
    var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");
    var toReturn;

    $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(category), function () {
        console.log(this.contactCategoryId, categoryId);
        if (this.contactCategoryId == categoryId) {
            toReturn = this.name;
            return false;
        }
    });

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Did you add console.log lines and see what is going on? You also do not return anything if there is no match.

Comment: if i put console.log in getContactCategoryById, i can see the value. If the value is not found, i don't want any value.

Comment: `console.log(this.contactCategoryId, categoryId);`

Comment: 1 3 ,
2 3 , 
3 3 ,
1 2 ,
2 2 ,
3 2 ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning from a `jQuery.each` which is itself a function and so your return value gets swallowed up by `jQuery.each` and your helper function `getContactCategoryById` ends up not returning anything (or always returning `undefined` to be precise).

What you need to do is stop the loop once you find what you need, and then return what you found after the loop has finished:

```
function getContactCategoryById(categoryId) {
    var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");
    var foundName = '';
    $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(category), function () {
        if (this.contactCategoryId == categoryId) {
            foundName = this.name;
            return false; // returning false in jQuery.each stops the iteration
        }
    });
    return foundName; // return the name you found
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's the solution a found a few minutes ago.